# How do i read a visual studio file using filing and store the input as a word file

Tags: c#, c++, .net, visual-studio

What im essentially trying to do is read a entire folder that contains a visual studio project and then read the .cpp file extensions and .cs extensions and somehow store all the copied information onto a word and or text file.
I am already aware i have to use office automation to store it onto a word file.
The issue arises that how would i read the .cpp file , since fstream doesn't recognize .cpp for me

An example cpp file which i'd like to copy onto a text or word file

'''

```
int main()
{
a =2; 
b=3;}
```

'''

the output file as a .txt or .word should have this word to word

Comment: What have you already tried to solve your issue? Please show us your relevant [mcve].

Comment: C++ file streams don't care at all about what a file is called or what it contains. They don't "recognize" anything.

Comment: i was using exception handling to see if the file even opens in the first place , that's what i meant by doesn't recognize, if i change the extension to .txt it opens without issues.

Comment: .cpp and .cs files _are_ Text files. So you should be able to concat them in a shell script (or batch script or powershell; example cmd: `type  *.cs > allcs.txt`). It just doesn't make sense to me to do so. Just out of curiosity: what are you trying to do?

Comment: You really should consider better alternatives, like creating a zip file with those files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out since me and my friend both were working on this project apparently my f stream library is 'corrupted' or something was wrong with it , a clean install of the library (in my case reinstalling visual studio fixed the issue and now i can read .cpp files and all other extensions as well which i wasn't able to do so before)

here is a sample code for what i've done to read and filter out cpp files from an entire directory that im getting using the filesystem namespace

```
string check_file_extension(string file_p = "C/Desktop")
{
    // a function used to get the file extention



    return file_p.substr(file_p.length()-4); // gets the last 4 charecters of the file path mentioned , utilized later to check extention in main
}

void OpenandSaveFile(string file_p = "Null")
{
    // a function used to save and retrive file data 
    // utilizes f stream

    ifstream file_obj;
    string out_put;
    file_obj.open(file_p);
    while (!file_obj.eof())
    {

        file_obj >> out_put;
        cout << out_put;

    }
    file_obj.close();


}


string path;
cout << "Please enter your file path " << endl;
cin >> path;


for (const auto & entry : fs::directory_iterator(path)) // gets the entire list of files in the specified directory
{
    string curr_file = entry.path().string();
    cout << entry.path() << endl;
    if (check_file_extension(curr_file) == ".cpp")
    {
        OpenandSaveFile(curr_file);
    }
}
```

This doesn't write to a file but reading is ample at this moment in case some one else runs into a similar problem

Also thanks Christopher , i know its incredibly stupid they asked me to just write it onto a word file which literally makes no sense but yeah here i am ;c

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to use Office Automation. Or rather it depends wich Office Fromat you need to support. There are 3 basic cases when working with Office Formats from C#/.NET:

- you only need to supprot the new Formats, like docx. You can use the [OpenXML SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk), any of the wrapper around it. Or even just the XMLWriter and ZipArchive classes.
- if you need to support the old formats too, the only way is the (T)rusty office COM interop. It has all the usual limits of COM interop, and **also** requires office to be installed and will only run in an interactive session
- for combinations of any very specific problem, any specific formats and any specific GUI technologies there might be a 3rd way.

I adivse the OpenXML way. In fact jsut tell them with .doc it is impossible or takes 10 times the time and requirements. This is a fair assesment.

However this whole operation also sounds capital W Wrong. This is either a very poorly thought through Management decision or you missreading the requirements massively. I literally can not think of a case where this would make even remote sense. It is somewhere around "printing out the source code" level of bad idea.